# Given a Lebesgue measurable set I ⊂ R so that m(I) = π, there is a subset A ⊂ I so that m(A) = e (euler number).

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Problem: I have to solve this problem about the Lebesgue measure, where given a Lebesgue measurable set I ⊂ R so that m(I) = π, I need to prove that there exists a subset A ⊂ I so that m(A) = e (euler number).

My idea: I have been thinking about it, and I thought that maybe those numbers are just there to distract you from the real problem. I guessed that maybe, given any set I ⊂ R so that m(I) = a, for every 0≤b≤a, there should be a Lebesgue measurable subset A ⊂ I so that m(A) = b.
I think it makes sense, but it's just an idea, and I don't know how to prove it or even if I'm right.
Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The idea expressed in your second paragraph is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $0<a<b$ and $m(I)=b.$

Let $F(x) = m(I\cap(-\infty, x]). $

See if you can prove that $F$ is continuous and $F(x)\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$ and $F(x)\to a$ as $x\to+\infty.$

Then apply the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Use continuity of the function $f(x)=m(I \cap (-\infty,x])$ and the intermediate value theorem